# I am getting errors when deploying to Vercel. Can anyone help me with the my issues below?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, environment-variables

Cloning github.com/gmcnally78/-Final-Data-Driven-FullStack-App2 (Branch: main, Commit: e1d0133)

Cloning completed: 643.936ms

Analyzing source code...

Installing build runtime...

Build runtime installed: 2.278s

Looking up build cache...

Build Cache not found

Installing dependencies...

yarn install v1.22.17

[1/4] Resolving packages...

[2/4] Fetching packages...

[3/4] Linking dependencies...

warning " > @chakra-ui/icons@1.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "@chakra-ui/system@>=1.0.0".

warning "@chakra-ui/icons > @chakra-ui/icon@1.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "@chakra-ui/system@>=1.0.0".

warning "@emotion/styled > @emotion/babel-plugin@11.7.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".

warning "@emotion/styled > @emotion/babel-plugin > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.16.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".

warning "next > styled-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.14.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".

warning " > eslint-config-next@11.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^7.23.0".

warning "eslint-config-next > @typescript-eslint/parser@4.29.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0".

warning "eslint-config-next > eslint-import-resolver-typescript@2.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@*".

warning "eslint-config-next > eslint-plugin-import@2.23.4" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^2 || ^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7.2.0".

warning "eslint-config-next > eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7".

warning "eslint-config-next > eslint-plugin-react@7.24.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7".

warning "eslint-config-next > eslint-plugin-react-hooks@4.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0".

[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Saved lockfile.

Done in 47.72s.

Detected Next.js version: 11.1.3

Running "yarn run build"

yarn run v1.22.17

$ next build

info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5

Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.

This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.

You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:

https://nextjs.org/telemetry

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:

npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:

https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating

info  - Checking validity of types...

warn  - No ESLint configuration detected. Run next lint to begin setup

info  - Creating an optimized production build...

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:

npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:

https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating

Failed to compile.

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Header' in '/vercel/path0/pages/todos'

> Build error occurred

Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors

```
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:397:19

at async Span.traceAsyncFn
```

(/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
at async Object.build [as default]

(/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:77:25)

error Command failed with exit code 1.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1

info  - Loaded env from /Users/gregmcnally/Downloads/CS55.13-todo-app-week-8-main/.env.local

info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5

Failed to compile.

./pages/ssr-no-token.tsx:62:51

Type error: Argument of type 'IncomingMessage & { cookies: NextApiRequestCookies; }' is
not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.

Type 'IncomingMessage & { cookies: NextApiRequestCookies; }' is not assignable to type 'null'.

VS CODE
60 |   // `withAuthUserTokenSSR`.
61 |   const token = await AuthUser.getIdToken()

> 62 |   const endpoint = getAbsoluteURL('/api/example', req)
> |                                                   ^
> 63 |   const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
> 64 |     method: 'GET',
> 65 |     headers: {
> info  - Checking validity of types .npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! todo-app-week08@0.1.0 build: `next build`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the todo-app-week08@0.1.0 build script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gregmcnally/.npm/_logs/2021-12-16T06_44_01_675Z-debug.log
gregmcnally@Gregs-MBP CS55.13-todo-app-week-8-main %

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add the specific error you are facing, there is no need to add the whole story. Please also show what effort you made in solving the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd recommend that you try run:

`yarn build` or `npm run build` locally, as you'll be able to catch a lot of these errors before attempting to deploy on Vercel.

There are a few errors:

`ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Header' in '/vercel/path0/pages/todos'`

Tells us that your project is unable to resolve an import for the "Header" component in your todos page. Have a look at that page in your project and ensure you're using the right import path.

Secondly, there is a type error in `ssr-no-token.tsx:` and so type validation is causing the build to fail.

```
 Type error: Argument of type 'IncomingMessage & { cookies: NextApiRequestCookies; }' is 
not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.
```

If we look at the error message we can see that you need to add checks to ensure that cookies is not `null` or `undefined` (and is the type `NextApiRequestCookies`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I turns out that these errors was because of the environment variables wasn't put in correctly. in one of my variables I had a key for a value that I copied and pasted in from my .env.local file. The key had single quotes on the beginning and end of the key, so I removed those and I was able to deploy my app. Thanks, Again for replying

Answer (score 0):

You can test the Vercel deploy command locally with debug logs using the following command:

```
vercel build -d
```

In my case, I was getting errors related to the `project.json` file in the `.vercel/` folder. The "installCommand" and "rootDirectory" fields were null so I updated them:

```
{
  "projectId": "{project_id}",
  "orgId": "{org_id}",
  "settings": {
    "createdAt": 1701610725426,
    "framework": null,
    "devCommand": null,
    "installCommand": "npm install",
    "buildCommand": null,
    "outputDirectory": "api",
    "rootDirectory": "src",
    "directoryListing": false,
    "nodeVersion": "18.x"
  }
}
```